# Query average point each student

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

Student:

```
   id       name     
   2        ABC      
   13       DEF      
   22       GHI
```

Semester:

```
   id       student_id     sem     marks                                    
   1        2              1       {"math":3,   "physic":4,   "chemis":5}   
   2        2              2       {"math":2.5, "physic":4.5, "chemis":5}   
   3        2              3       {"math":3,   "physic":3.5, "chemis":4}   
   5        13             1       {"math":3,   "physic":4,   "chemis":5}   
   6        13             2       {"math":3,   "physic":4,   "chemis":5}
```

So e.g with student_id=2:

average marks = ((3+4+5)/3)+(2.5+4.5+5)/3+(3+3.5+4)/3)/3 = 3.83

Is there any way to query average marks group by student ID?

```
   student_id      average     number_of_sems     
   2               3.83        3                  
   13              xxx         2
```

I'm trying to count by subject:

```
SELECT
  t1.student_id,
  t1.count,
  (SELECT sum(xx.count)
   FROM
     (SELECT (marks:: JSON ->> 'math') :: DOUBLE PRECISION AS count
      FROM "Semester"
      WHERE student_id= t1.student_id) AS xx)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      student_id,
      count(1)
    FROM "Semester"
    GROUP BY student_id
  ) AS t1;
```

But still don't know how to continue. This might be bad solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This includes the students without marks:

```
SELECT st.id, avg(m.value)
FROM student st
   LEFT JOIN semester se
      ON st.id = se.student_id
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT value::numeric
                      FROM jsonb_each_text(se.marks)
                     ) m
      ON TRUE
GROUP BY st.id;

┌────┬────────────────────┐
│ id │        avg         │
├────┼────────────────────┤
│  2 │ 3.8333333333333333 │
│ 13 │ 4.0000000000000000 │
│ 22 │                    │
└────┴────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thank you for reminding avg - I divided sum by count :)

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
select student_id
, avg((marks->>m)::float) average
, count(distinct sem) number_of_sems
from semestr s
join student t on s.student_id = t.id
left outer join json_object_keys(marks) m on true
group by student_id;
 student_id |     average      | number_of_sems
------------+------------------+----------------
          2 | 3.83333333333333 |              3
         13 |                4 |              2
(3 rows)
```

**updated**

as pozs remarked - we probably should calculate semesters with no exams still as semestres...

Comment: This will only work, when `marks` cannot be `NULL`, and `{}` (empty object) neither.

Comment: That's on OP, but he/she didn't specify. But deferred semesters are semesters & it won't hurt the `avg()` anyway (at least it worths a note IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for an idea that using json_each_text() and avg() funtion.
So in case if the purpose is getting average mark in each subject of 1 student:

```
SELECT 
     st.id,
     json_data.key AS subject, 
     SUM(json_data.value::DOUBLE PRECISION) AS sum_value,
     avg(json_data.value::DOUBLE PRECISION) AS avg_value
FROM student  AS st,
json_each_text(st.marks::JSON) AS json_data
GROUP BY si.id, subject;
```